# Is it possible to cache google map in a flutter app?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dictionary, dart

I’m making a flutter app and I need google map in it but it reloads each time I reopen the app I want to know if there is a way for me to cache google map inside my app to prevent this reloading

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is quite open-ended. Could you provide a bit more information on what you've tried so far, or any code you've written?

Comment: In google map‘s app after you’ve chosen a location if you exit the app and return again the map doesn’t reload in fact the location and it’s area are seemingly cached inside the application 
I want to implement this feature in my flutter app but I don’t know even if it is possible or not
If it is how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to prevent reloading? Caching Google Maps might be in violation of their [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3.-license.).

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround maybe using [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview). It allows you to have an image of some region on the map, which can be downloaded without loading an entire map.

As per [jabamataro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11269204/jabamataro)’s comment, caching is a violation of [Google Maps policy 3.2.3(b)](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms). So, no caching

Example use:

```
static String mapPreviewImage({double latitude, double longitude}) {
    return 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&$latitude,$longitude&zoom=16&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C$latitude,$longitude&key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY';
  }
```

So, you can use returned String as URL for your http request

Comment: I believe downloading and caching Google Maps content might be in violation of Google Maps Platform Terms of Service particularly in item 3.2.3 (b) No caching: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3.-license.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @jabamataro, downloading and caching might be against [Google Maps' ToS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) (as of Oct 21 2021)

> (a)  No Scraping. Customer will not export, extract, or otherwise scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, Customer will not: (i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download Google Maps tiles, Street View images, geocodes, directions, distance matrix results, roads information, places information, elevation values, and time zone details; (iii) copy and save business names, addresses, or user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services.